# sql pivot column data into rows

Tags: sql, pivot

I'm working with a table in SQL workbench.

I have a table with population data that looks like the following(with dumbed down population numbers for ease):

```
State   2010   2011  2012  2013  2014  2015
Alaska    5     8     10    13    15    19
```

I want to convert this table into a table that looks like the following:

```
State    Year   Estimate
Alaska    2010     5
Alaska    2011     8
Alaska    2012     10
Alaska    2013     13
Alaska    2014     15
Alaska    2015     19
```

What statement do I need to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Garrett

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

`Union all` is a general purpose method:

```
select state, '2010' as year, "2010" as Estimate from t
union all
select state, '2011' as year, "2011" as Estimate from t
union all
select state, '2012' as year, "2012" as Estimate from t
union all
select state, '2013' as year, "2013" as Estimate from t
union all
select state, '2014' as year, "2014" as Estimate from t
union all
select state, '2015' as year, "2015" as Estimate from t;
```

There are other methods that are more efficient (particularly for larger tables).  My preferred is to use a lateral join (either using the `lateral` or `apply` keywords).  SQL also offers a very specific syntax for unpivoting.